# GA event tracking code not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics, universal-analytics

We placed the event tracking code on the form on the below page, looking for it to fire when the form is submitted.

https://www.bobbarker.com/customer/account/create/

The code can be seen below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        var dataForm = new VarienForm('form-validate', true);

        Form.getElements('form-validate').each(function(element) {
            element.setAttribute('autocomplete', 'off');
        });

        $('form-validate').observe('submit', function(e) {
            ga('send', 'event', 'form', 'submit', 'request an account');
        });
        //]]>
    </script>
```

We're not seeing events come through to GA.

Thanks,
Jacob

Comment: Where are you looking exactly? and when did you create the account and add the code?

Comment: Fairly sure this: `$('form-validate').observe` won't work. Is that an **id** selector, a **class** selector or what? As it's written it looks like an **element** selector except that there is no such thing as a `<form-validate />` element.

Comment: How is your form being submitted? Is it a regular form submit in the browser or is it an ajax send?

Comment: Seems to be a typo in your selector, as @gforce301 said also. As such, this may be off-topic. "This question was caused by a **problem that can no longer be reproduced** or a **simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the [shortest program necessary](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce the problem before posting."

Comment: I think even if he fixes the typo, it still won't work. If it's a regular form submit, then the browser is going to cancel the ajax call that google uses to send the event. Since the OP won't give any feedback to questions asked in comments, this appears to be unsalvageable.

Answer (score 0):

Before use event track, try create a ga session in end of your page, like this:

```html
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
</script>
</body>
```